# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'. This error occurs when I try to insert popped value in array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a code that takes binary string as input and when we rotate that string, it computes maximum value of that string in decimal form.

```
def maximumPower(s):
    arr = [int(arr) for arr in str(s)]
    su = 0
    length = len(arr)
    k = 0
    countn = 0
    for i in range(length):
        arr = arr.insert(0,arr.pop())
        for j in range(length-1,-1):
            for k in range(length):
                su = su+((2**j)*new_arr[k])
            if su%2 == 0:
                countn = su & (~(su-1))
                break
        if countn != 0:
            break
    return countn
```

Comment: `arr = arr.insert(...)`—`insert` returns None, so you are assigning None to `arr`.

Comment: What do you mean by ```maximum value of that string in decimal form```?

Answer (score 2):

`arr.insert()` dosent have return value, it updates the array/list. So you are assigning None to arr again, and it becomes None. So use `arr.insert(0,arr.pop())` instead of `arr = arr.insert(0,arr.pop())`.